# "Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException" al usar AddView()

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> Diagrama: A la **izquierda** están los pasos *lógicos* que sigo, a la derecha las dos layouts.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, esta es la parte del código relevante que yo tengo en mi `ActivityMain`

```
bButton.Click += delegate{
    
    
    LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout2);//En esta línea layout queda a "null"
    contenidoPrincipal.RemoveAllViews(); //Contenido principal es la ScrollView
    contenidoPrincipal.AddView(layout); //Aquí me tira Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException

}
```

Se me ha ocurrido que podría ser por que `MainActivity` tiene cargado `ActivityMain.axml` como **vista**, si es así, **¿Como podría hacer para cargar la `LinearLayout` en la `ScrollView`?

Ya he comprobado que todos los Id's a los que llamo existan.

## Objetivo:

Ir cambiando el contenido de la App sin cambiar la `Toolbar` ni los  botones que te permiten cambiar entre las distintas vistas.

También dejo por aquí el cómo es la layout real que utilizo, esperando que se pueda entender lo que estoy intentando hacer. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Dejo por aquí también tanto el StackTrace que me da la excepción como el Mensaje.

## StackTrace:

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <09bf3e262b934ffab2ba01f9fc7fd54d>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <09bf3e262b934ffab2ba01f9fc7fd54d>:0 
at Android.Views.ViewGroup.AddView (Android.Views.View child) [0x00031] in <25661073a35344a89f215a4cf81af37c>:0 
at NombreApp.MainActivity.<OnCreate>b__11_0 (System.Object <p0>, System.EventArgs <p1>) [0x0001a] in C:\\Proyectos\\DirectorioApp\\NombreApp\\MainActivity.cs:71  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4191)
android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4173)
mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
 mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)\n\tat android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)\n\tat android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6378)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
```

## Mensaje:

```
Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo usando `LayoutInflater`. Ya que en principio no puedes pasar directamente un `LinearLayout` por parámetro al `AddView()`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity, null, false);
contenidoPrincipal.AddView(v);
```

*1:

View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.**activity**, null, false);
Este **activity** debe de ser el nombre de tu "`Layout.axml`", la que estás intentando añadir a `ActivityMain`.